# Обработчик события click срабатывает два раза

Tags: события, click, javascript-events, mouse-event, onclicklistener

При клике обработчик события срабатывает два раза.
А нужно, что бы срабатывал один раз.
Из-за этого не получается отобразить/скрыть элемент при клике.
Гугл не отвечает. Подскажите, что делать?

```js
(function() {
  var classToggle = 'js-toggleSwitchingContent',
    classContent = 'js-switchingContent',
    classIsActive = 'is-active',
    toggles = document.querySelectorAll('.' + classToggle);

  for (var i = 0; i < toggles.length; i++) {
    var toggle = toggles[i];
    toggle.addEventListener('click', toggleClickHundler);
  }

  var content;

  function toggleClickHundler(e) {
    console.log("toggleClickHundler", e.target.tagName, e.target.getAttribute("class"));

    content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.classList.contains(classContent)) {
      content.classList.toggle(classIsActive);
    }
  }
})();
```

```html
<div class="toggle js-toggleSwitchingContent">
  <label class="toggle__fakeLabel">
            <input class="toggle__fakeCheckbox" name="" type="checkbox">
            <div class="toggle__line">
                <div class="toggle__spot"></div>
            </div>
    </label>
</div>
<div class="switchingContent js-switchingContent">
  content_here
</div>
```

Comment: Ну исходя из кода судя по всему у вас несклько элементов в массиве toggles, вы вешаете обработчик на несколько элементов идёт всплытие вызываются соответственно все обработчики клика. для более подробного надо иметь полный код.

Comment: toggles.length == 1

Answer (score 2):

Вешайте конкретно на `input` событие.

```js
(function() {
  var classToggle = 'toggle__fakeCheckbox',
    classContent = 'js-switchingContent',
    classIsActive = 'is-active',
    toggles = document.querySelectorAll('.' + classToggle);

  for (var i = 0; i < toggles.length; i++) {
    var toggle = toggles[i];
    toggle.addEventListener('click', toggleClickHundler);
  }

  var content;

  function toggleClickHundler(e) {
    console.log("toggleClickHundler");
    content = this.parentNode.parentNode.nextElementSibling;
    console.log(content)
    if (content.classList.contains(classContent)) {
      content.classList.toggle(classIsActive);
    }
  }
})();
```

```html
<div class="toggle js-toggleSwitchingContent">
  <label class="toggle__fakeLabel">
            <input class="toggle__fakeCheckbox" name="" type="checkbox">
            <div class="toggle__line">
                <div class="toggle__spot"></div>
            </div>
    </label>
</div>
<div class="switchingContent js-switchingContent">
  content_here
</div>
```

Comment: Или событие click для label повесть нужно в return false"
Каким образом это лучше сделать?

Comment: @Rabbit добавил.

Comment: @EVG Обработчик, тем не менее, во втором фрагменте вызывается дважды при клике на текст лейбла.

Comment: @Igor да действительно. Удаляю,не работает. Значет надо всецело переписывать поведение label и input под эти нужды, ну или что правильней.не вешать на label или делать проверку но событие всёравно будет вызываться

Answer (score 1):

```js
(function() {
  var classToggle = 'js-toggleSwitchingContent',
    classContent = 'js-switchingContent',
    classIsActive = 'is-active',
    toggles = document.querySelectorAll('.' + classToggle + " input[type='checkbox']");

  for (var i = 0; i < toggles.length; i++) {
    var toggle = toggles[i];
    toggle.addEventListener('click', toggleClickHundler);
  }

  var content;

  function toggleClickHundler(e) {
    console.log("toggleClickHundler", e.target.tagName, e.target.getAttribute("class"));

    content = this.closest(".toggle").nextElementSibling;
    content.classList.toggle(classIsActive);
  }
})();
```

```css
.switchingContent {
  display:none;
  height:30px;
  border:1px solid blue;
  background-color:lightgreen;
}

.is-active {
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="toggle js-toggleSwitchingContent">
  <label class="toggle__fakeLabel">Test
            <input class="toggle__fakeCheckbox" name="" type="checkbox">Test
            <div class="toggle__line">
                <div class="toggle__spot"></div>
            </div>
    </label>
</div>
<div class="switchingContent js-switchingContent">
  content_here
</div>
```